# Adding support to Convert text to html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable with some text with html tags. When I dispaly it in my page I want to change the tags to html? How can I achieve this.

```
var myVar = "<h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Paragraph</p>
            <a href="www.google.com">More...</a>"

<p id="myP">Here I want to display myVar, so it should be Heading (h1), then paragraph, and the link</p>
```

Comment: Is this html coming from a user?

Comment: Its actually comming to db.

Comment: Alright, just being sure; because, any HTML that comes from the user is a massive security risk. If you were ever to try something like that, you should provide your own syntax and build a parser that converts your custom syntax to HTML. That way you control all input.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `Element.innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById('myP').innerHTML = myVar;
```

Make sure `myVar` is a valid string though.

Comment: If `myP` already has content; then, this will overwrite the existing content. You can prepend or append the new content instead of setting. It's like adding strings. `var myString = "bob"; myString = myString + " is blue"; //appending new content`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this:

```js
var myVar = `<h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Paragraph</p>
            <a href="www.google.com">More...</a>`;

document.getElementById('myP').innerHTML = myVar;
```

```html
<p id="myP"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `var` declaration is wrong.

```
var myVar = '<h1>Heading</h1>'+
            '<p>Paragraph</p>'+
            '<a href="www.google.com">More...</a>';
```

Then you can do this

```
document.getElementById('myP').innerHTML = myVar;
```